# Meaning (Definition) of "Decays Exponentially"?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

When I look this up I get an unambiguous definition that $f(x) $ decays exponentially if it is a function of the form $f(x) = Ae^{-\lambda x}$ for some real $A$ and $\lambda > 0$. This fits my expectation up to a point, but doesn't deal with an exercise I'm doing: "show $x e^{-x}$ decays exponentially as $x \to \infty$". Clearly this is not a function of the form $Ae^{-\lambda x}$.

**Might exponential decay mean that there exists some real $A$, $\lambda > 0$, and $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $|f(x)| < Ae^{-\lambda x}$ ?** In that case I can complete the exercise as follows"

Proposition: for $x > 2$, $x < e^{x/2}$. Proof: for $x > 2$, $x^2 > 2x$ so $e^{x/2} = 1 + x/2 + (1/2!).(x/2)^2 + ... > 1 + x/2 + x/2 + ... > x$.

Proposition: for $x > 2$, $|x e^{-x}| < e^{-x/2}$ and therefore decays exponentially. Proof: $ 0 < x e^{-x} < e^{x/2}e^{-x} = e^{-x/2}$.

However, I'm left with some doubts about my interpretation. Does $f(x) = 0$ decay exponentially ? I would think it fails to satisfy the "decay" part. **So, should the term refer to a non-zero function with modulus bounded by a diminishing exponential, or even a function which is approximated in some way by a diminishing exponential ?**

To take the given exercise further ...

Proposition: for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $ x < e^{\epsilon x}$. Proof: for any $\epsilon, n$ there is $x_0$ such that $x_0 > ((n+1)!/\epsilon^{n+1})^{1/n}$. Then $(\epsilon  x_0)^{n+1}/(n+1)! = x_0.\epsilon  ^{n+1}.x_0^n/(n+1)! > x_0 \implies e^{\epsilon x_0} > x_0$

Proposition: $xe^{-x} $ is "approximated" by a decreasing exponential function. Proof: for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $x_o$ such that for $x > x_0$, $e^{-x} < xe^{-x} < e^{(\epsilon - 1)x}$

**I'd appreciate feedback on the meaning of this term.**

**Actually, to clarify my question following some feedback, it's the *definition* I'm looking for rather than an interpretation of its meaning.**

Comment: it depends on the context. In the context of Laplace transforms, it is obvious what means having an exponential decay

Comment: @user1952009. Thanks for the feedback. It seems common in maths to define terms, even the obvious ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the exponential decay is essentially a decay so strong that it beats the growth of any polynomial: for any $\lambda>0$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)e^{-\lambda x}=0.$$

You could claim that $P(x)e^{-\lambda x}$ is not a "pure" exponential decay. But considering

$$A:=\max_x\left(P(x)e^{-\lambda x/2}\right)$$ we have

$$P(x)e^{-\lambda x}\le Ae^{-\lambda x/2},$$ so that $P(x)e^{-\lambda x}$ actually decreases faster than an exponential of coefficient $\lambda/2$.

---

You can feel it by looking at a plot of $\log\left(P(x)e^{-\lambda x}\right)=\log(P(x))-\lambda x$ for various polynomials, which is always asymptotic to a straight line.

[image]

---

A clean definition is indeed:

There exists some real $A$, $\lambda > 0$, and $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $|f(x)|\le Ae^{-\lambda x}$.

Or, in the big-O notation, simply

$$f(x)=O\left(e^{-\lambda x}\right).$$

Comment: in the context of Schwartz functions it could mean decay more than polynomial. In the context of entire functions, it could mean $\log f(z) \sim -cz$ or even $\log f(z) \sim c z^k$

Comment: @user1952009: the context is given by the OP: functions bounded by $Ae^{-\lambda x}$. What do you mean by "decay more than polynomial" ???

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space (and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform)

Comment: @user1952009: 1) polynomials do not decay, 2) this link is about "rapidly decreasing functions", not exponentially decreasing ones; I don't see the relevance.

Comment: The relevance is that a decay $\approx \mathcal{O}(e^{-cx})$ is important in many situation, and depending on the context, we'll use a different definition for "exponential decay"  (convergence of Laplace transform, Schwartz functions, order of entire function, etc.)

Comment: @user1952009: no, you are confusing *rapid* and *exponential*. And polynomials do not decay.

Comment: lol... forget it (and read again the 1st line of your answer, and the 3 contexts I mentioned)

Comment: @user1952009: do polynomials decay ?

Comment: No, but in the context of Schwartz functions $\mathcal{O}(x^{-k})$ is called a polynomial decay.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I think that the beating of polynomial growth (which is part of the definition of functions in Schwartz space) is a consequence of exponential decay, but not its definition - else it might rather be called "faster than polynomial decay" ?

Comment: @TomCollinge: quite right, this is not the definition, which you clearly stated. For intuitive understanding, exponential decay is when the log-plot is linear. Faster decays can also be called "super-exponential". I would not recommend to use *exponential* for the *super-exponential* cases, this creates confusion. No problem for "polynomial *decay*" to denote the decay of the inverse of a polynomial, in some way "sub-exponential".

Answer (score 3):

In the field of Partial Differential Equations, we use to say that

> a solution $u$ of some differential equation decays exponentially fast (at infinity) if it can be bounded in the following way: $$|u(x)| \leq C \exp (-\alpha |x|)$$ for every $|x| \gg 1$, where $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ are suitable constants.

This is a very important property for solutions of a PDE (mainly of elliptic type), and it has been widely investigated in the literature. In our dialect, the exponential decay *never* refers to *being equal to* an exponential function, since this would (almost) never happen. The case that $u \equiv 0$ may, in principle, happen: anyway, for our purposes this is a trivial and totally clear situation.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to more or less coincide with my first guess. I think the condition $|x| >> 1$ is equatable to $x > x_0$ for some $x_0$.